# How do i translate this algorithm into Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I translate this algorithm to be applicable in Microsoft Excel:

```
For each value in A:A

Check values in C:C

If A[i] - C[j] = 30 minutes 

Then D[j] = B[i]

Iterate
```

The below picture is an example of the time data:

[image: data]

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: -1 but I will remove it once you share what you've tried, as @CharlieRB mentioned.

Comment: Sorry for being late @Raystafarian i posted it as an answer as i worked it out. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cell D1:

```
=IF(ROUND((A1-C1)*24*60,1) = 30, B1,"")
```

Then drag it down for all your values.

This takes A1 - C1 which will give you a decimal representation in time, multiplies it by 24 and 60 to get it into minutes, rounds it off to the nearest whole minute, and finally evaluates if it's 30. If it is, it displays B1, if not, a blank cell.

Depending on your usage you may need to use < or > to include values that aren't exactly 30.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it works perfectly:

```
Sub Process()

Dim i,j,N,M as Integer

Dim Time_Diff as Integer

Dim TimeA,TimeC as Date

For i = 1 to 5
    TimeA=worksheets("Data").Range("A"&i).Value 
    For j = 1 to 17
        TimeC=worksheets("Data").Range("C"&j).Value 
        if  Datediff("n",TimeA,TimeC) = 30 then 
         worksheets("Data").Range("D"&j)=worksheets("Data").Range("B"&i)
         Goto SkipThis
         End if 
     Next j 
SkipThis:   
Next i

End sub
```